# Searching keywords in Multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following tables,

```
state : state_id, state_name
city  : city_id, city_name, state_id
category : category_id, category_name
products : product_id, product_name, cateogory_id, product_description, city_id
```

I want to search all the tables for a given keyword.

I tried using LIKE, which is returning many rows,

The code i tried,

```
keyword = 'apple';

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    products AS p, 
    categories AS cat, 
    city AS c, 
    state as s 
WHERE 
    p.category_id=cat.category_id 
    AND p.city_id=c.city_id 
    AND c.state_id=s.state_id 
    AND p.product_name LIKE '%apple%' 
    OR p.product_description LIKE '%apple%' 
    OR cat.category_name LIKE '%apple%' 
    OR c.city_name LIKE '%apple%' 
    OR s.state_name LIKE '%apple%'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query an exact match, use `=`:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    products AS p, 
    categories AS cat, 
    city AS c, 
    state as s 
WHERE 
    p.category_id=cat.category_id 
    AND p.city_id=c.city_id 
    AND c.state_id=s.state_id 
    AND p.product_name = 'apple' 
    OR p.product_description = 'apple'  
    OR cat.category_name LIKE = 'apple' 
    OR c.city_name LIKE = 'apple' 
    OR s.state_name LIKE = 'apple'
```

If you want to return all rows with the "apple" word, try to add blanks around it like that :

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    products AS p, 
    categories AS cat, 
    city AS c, 
    state as s 
WHERE 
    p.category_id=cat.category_id 
    AND p.city_id=c.city_id 
    AND c.state_id=s.state_id 
    AND p.product_name LIKE '% apple%' 
    OR p.product_name LIKE '%apple %' 
    OR p.product_description LIKE '% apple%' 
    OR p.product_description LIKE '%apple %' 
    OR cat.category_name LIKE '% apple%' 
    OR cat.category_name LIKE '%apple %' 
    OR c.city_name LIKE '% apple%' 
    OR c.city_name LIKE '%apple %' 
    OR s.state_name LIKE '% apple%'
    OR s.state_name LIKE '%apple %'
```